# Python Pandas Create New DataFrame Using Existing DataFrame to Query Another DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, merge

My goal is to build a new `DataFrame` named `df3` (dataframe 3).

Using `df1`'s `['Header 1', 'Header 2', 'Normalized']` values, how do I look in `df2` rows to find where `df1` `['Header 1', 'Header 2', 'Normalized']` is equal to `df2` `['Header 1', 'Header 2', 'Normalized']` and build a new `DataFrame` from the result?

For example, in row `0` of `df1`, the `Header 1`, `Header 2`, and `Normalized` equal `df2` rows `0`, `1`.

`df1`

```
            Header 1 Header 2    Header 3 Normalized    Status Match type
0             Boston  Label 1  "phrase 1"   phrase 1  eligible     Phrase
1       DC/Baltimore  Label 2  [phrase 2]   phrase 2  eligible      Exact
2          Philly/NJ  Label 3  "phrase 3"   phrase 3  eligible     Phrase
3          Philly/NJ  Label 4  "phrase 4"   phrase 4  eligible     Phrase
4          Philly/NJ  Label 5  "phrase 5"   phrase 5  eligible     Phrase
5           Portland  Label 6  "phrase 6"   phrase 6  eligible     Phrase
6  Raleigh/Charlotte  Label 7  [phrase 7]   phrase 7  eligible      Exact
7  Raleigh/Charlotte  Label 8  "phrase 8"   phrase 8  eligible     Phrase
```

`df2`

```
             Header 1  Header 2     Header 3 Normalized    Status Match type
0              Boston   Label 1   +phrase +1   phrase 1  eligible      Broad
1              Boston   Label 1   [phrase 1]   phrase 1  eligible      Exact
2        DC/Baltimore   Label 2   +phrase +2   phrase 2  eligible      Broad
3        DC/Baltimore   Label 2   "phrase 2"   phrase 2  eligible     Phrase
4                Frag  Label 22       [what]       what  eligible      Exact
5           Philly/NJ   Label 3   +phrase +3   phrase 3  eligible      Broad
6           Philly/NJ   Label 4   +phrase +4   phrase 4  eligible      Broad
7           Philly/NJ   Label 5   +phrase +5   phrase 5  eligible      Broad
8           Philly/NJ   Label 3   [phrase 3]   phrase 3  eligible      Exact
9           Philly/NJ   Label 4   [phrase 4]   phrase 4  eligible      Exact
10          Philly/NJ   Label 5   [phrase 5]   phrase 5  eligible      Exact
11           Portland   Label 6   +phrase +6   phrase 6  eligible      Broad
12           Portland   Label 6   [phrase 6]   phrase 6  eligible      Exact
13  Raleigh/Charlotte   Label 7   +phrase +7   phrase 7  eligible      Broad
14  Raleigh/Charlotte   Label 8   +phrase +8   phrase 8  eligible      Broad
15  Raleigh/Charlotte   Label 7   "phrase 7"   phrase 7  eligible     Phrase
16  Raleigh/Charlotte   Label 8   [phrase 8]   phrase 8  eligible      Exact
```

`df3` final result from this example would include all rows from `df1` and every row from `df2` except row (`index`) `4` because its `['Header 1', 'Header 2', 'Normalized']` does not match any row in `df1`.

The key thing I don't understand is how to use multiple criteria from one DataFrame to filter data in another DataFrame?

**Edit 1:**
My end-goal is to have `df3` look like the below table.  The key thing to note is that it `merges` `df1` and `df2` **entire rows** where `['Header 1', 'Header 2', 'Normalized']` are equal.  I've tried the `merge` suggestions.  It looks exactly like what I need but I see column headers with suffixes `_x`, `_y` appended.  How do I output the below in one swoop?  Do I have to change header labels to match that of the original table and drop a few columns?  Or is there a better approach?

```
             Header 1   Header 2  Header 3   Normalized  Status   Match type
0              Boston   Label 1   "phrase 1"   phrase 1  eligible     Phrase
1        DC/Baltimore   Label 2   [phrase 2]   phrase 2  eligible     Exact
2           Philly/NJ   Label 3   "phrase 3"   phrase 3  eligible     Phrase
3           Philly/NJ   Label 4   "phrase 4"   phrase 4  eligible     Phrase
4           Philly/NJ   Label 5   "phrase 5"   phrase 5  eligible     Phrase
5            Portland   Label 6   "phrase 6"   phrase 6  eligible     Phrase
6   Raleigh/Charlotte   Label 7   [phrase 7]   phrase 7  eligible     Exact
7   Raleigh/Charlotte   Label 8   "phrase 8"   phrase 8  eligible     Phrase
0              Boston   Label 1   +phrase +1   phrase 1  eligible     Broad
1              Boston   Label 1   [phrase 1]   phrase 1  eligible     Exact
2        DC/Baltimore   Label 2   +phrase +2   phrase 2  eligible     Broad
3        DC/Baltimore   Label 2   "phrase 2"   phrase 2  eligible     Phrase
5           Philly/NJ   Label 3   +phrase +3   phrase 3  eligible     Broad
6           Philly/NJ   Label 4   +phrase +4   phrase 4  eligible     Broad
7           Philly/NJ   Label 5   +phrase +5   phrase 5  eligible     Broad
8           Philly/NJ   Label 3   [phrase 3]   phrase 3  eligible     Exact
9           Philly/NJ   Label 4   [phrase 4]   phrase 4  eligible     Exact
10          Philly/NJ   Label 5   [phrase 5]   phrase 5  eligible     Exact
11           Portland   Label 6   +phrase +6   phrase 6  eligible     Broad
12           Portland   Label 6   [phrase 6]   phrase 6  eligible     Exact
13  Raleigh/Charlotte   Label 7   +phrase +7   phrase 7  eligible     Broad
14  Raleigh/Charlotte   Label 8   +phrase +8   phrase 8  eligible     Broad
15  Raleigh/Charlotte   Label 7   "phrase 7"   phrase 7  eligible     Phrase
16  Raleigh/Charlotte   Label 8   [phrase 8]   phrase 8  eligible     Exact
```

Comment: Your problem here is to define what the criteria should be for whether the final value should be the lhs or the rhs one

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfect example of where you'd want to use `pandas.merge` (basically the Pandas equivalent on SQL JOIN, but where columns equality is the only join condition allowed):

```
df3 = pandas.merge(df1, df2, on=['Header 1','Header 2', 'Normalized'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a `left` style `merge`:

```
In [99]:

df.merge(df1, on=['Header 1','Header 2', 'Normalized'], how='left')
Out[99]:
             Header 1 Header 2  Header 3_x Normalized  Status_x Match type_x  \
0              Boston  Label 1    phrase 1   phrase 1  eligible       Phrase   
1              Boston  Label 1    phrase 1   phrase 1  eligible       Phrase   
2        DC/Baltimore  Label 2  [phrase 2]   phrase 2  eligible        Exact   
3        DC/Baltimore  Label 2  [phrase 2]   phrase 2  eligible        Exact   
4           Philly/NJ  Label 3    phrase 3   phrase 3  eligible       Phrase   
5           Philly/NJ  Label 3    phrase 3   phrase 3  eligible       Phrase   
6           Philly/NJ  Label 4    phrase 4   phrase 4  eligible       Phrase   
7           Philly/NJ  Label 4    phrase 4   phrase 4  eligible       Phrase   
8           Philly/NJ  Label 5    phrase 5   phrase 5  eligible       Phrase   
9           Philly/NJ  Label 5    phrase 5   phrase 5  eligible       Phrase   
10           Portland  Label 6    phrase 6   phrase 6  eligible       Phrase   
11           Portland  Label 6    phrase 6   phrase 6  eligible       Phrase   
12  Raleigh/Charlotte  Label 7  [phrase 7]   phrase 7  eligible        Exact   
13  Raleigh/Charlotte  Label 7  [phrase 7]   phrase 7  eligible        Exact   
14  Raleigh/Charlotte  Label 8    phrase 8   phrase 8  eligible       Phrase   
15  Raleigh/Charlotte  Label 8    phrase 8   phrase 8  eligible       Phrase   

    Header 3_y  Status_y Match type_y  
0   +phrase +1  eligible        Broad  
1   [phrase 1]  eligible        Exact  
2   +phrase +2  eligible        Broad  
3     phrase 2  eligible       Phrase  
4   +phrase +3  eligible        Broad  
5   [phrase 3]  eligible        Exact  
6   +phrase +4  eligible        Broad  
7   [phrase 4]  eligible        Exact  
8   +phrase +5  eligible        Broad  
9   [phrase 5]  eligible        Exact  
10  +phrase +6  eligible        Broad  
11  [phrase 6]  eligible        Exact  
12  +phrase +7  eligible        Broad  
13    phrase 7  eligible       Phrase  
14  +phrase +8  eligible        Broad  
15  [phrase 8]  eligible        Exact
```

Comment: I added **Edit 1** to my question above.  I see that `merge` has a `suffixes=('_x', '_y')` which is applied to overlapping columns.  What is the best way to format this `DataFrame` so all columns here match the same columns in the original DataFrames so I can then concatenate `df1` with this new one `df3`?  Do I just need to drop columns I don't want (suffixes with `_x`) and change the headings on the ones I do want or is there a better way?

Comment: You can either `drop`, `rename` or just not select them in the merge. The reason they end up in the merge is because the values clash on lhs and rhs so it generates a column for both sides to preserve them

Answer (score 1):

I cannot take credit for answering this.  All credit goes to @EdChum and @maxymoo for steering me in the right direction with `merge`.  I don't know how efficient this is but posting it just in case anyone stumbles across this similar problem.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.read_csv('df1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('df2.csv')

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Header 1', 'Header 2', 'Normalized'], how='left')
df3 = df3.drop(['Header 3_x', 'Status_x', 'Match type_x'], axis=1)
df3.columns = ['Header 1', 'Header 2', 'Normalized', 'Header 3', 'Status', 'Match type']
df3 = df3[['Header 1', 'Header 2', 'Header 3', 'Normalized', 'Status', 'Match type']]

print(pd.concat([df1, df3]))
```

Outputs:

```
             Header 1 Header 2     Header 3 Normalized    Status Match type
0              Boston  Label 1   "phrase 1"   phrase 1  eligible     Phrase
1        DC/Baltimore  Label 2   [phrase 2]   phrase 2  eligible      Exact
2           Philly/NJ  Label 3   "phrase 3"   phrase 3  eligible     Phrase
3           Philly/NJ  Label 4   "phrase 4"   phrase 4  eligible     Phrase
4           Philly/NJ  Label 5   "phrase 5"   phrase 5  eligible     Phrase
5            Portland  Label 6   "phrase 6"   phrase 6  eligible     Phrase
6   Raleigh/Charlotte  Label 7   [phrase 7]   phrase 7  eligible      Exact
7   Raleigh/Charlotte  Label 8   "phrase 8"   phrase 8  eligible     Phrase
0              Boston  Label 1   +phrase +1   phrase 1  eligible      Broad
1              Boston  Label 1   [phrase 1]   phrase 1  eligible      Exact
2        DC/Baltimore  Label 2   +phrase +2   phrase 2  eligible      Broad
3        DC/Baltimore  Label 2   "phrase 2"   phrase 2  eligible     Phrase
4           Philly/NJ  Label 3   +phrase +3   phrase 3  eligible      Broad
5           Philly/NJ  Label 3   [phrase 3]   phrase 3  eligible      Exact
6           Philly/NJ  Label 4   +phrase +4   phrase 4  eligible      Broad
7           Philly/NJ  Label 4   [phrase 4]   phrase 4  eligible      Exact
8           Philly/NJ  Label 5   +phrase +5   phrase 5  eligible      Broad
9           Philly/NJ  Label 5   [phrase 5]   phrase 5  eligible      Exact
10           Portland  Label 6   +phrase +6   phrase 6  eligible      Broad
11           Portland  Label 6   [phrase 6]   phrase 6  eligible      Exact
12  Raleigh/Charlotte  Label 7   +phrase +7   phrase 7  eligible      Broad
13  Raleigh/Charlotte  Label 7   "phrase 7"   phrase 7  eligible     Phrase
14  Raleigh/Charlotte  Label 8   +phrase +8   phrase 8  eligible      Broad
15  Raleigh/Charlotte  Label 8   [phrase 8]   phrase 8  eligible      Exact
```